# Is there a neat way to separate checked checkbox labels in JS/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on method that has it's purpose to get elements from a form so that the form can be previewed before submitting. Currently I'm stuck on a problem where I'm trying to get labels from checked checkboxes and separate them. Getting the labels is no problem, but finding a neat way to split them with '( | )' is. I know adding an array possibly would solve my problem, but I was looking for an alternative way to do this in JS/Jquery by simply adding a built in method or similar.

**JS and Jquery for what I currently have:**

```
function previewForm() {
const previewPlace = document.getElementById('previewPlace');
let getPlaceChecked = $(':checkbox[name=placeCheckbox]:checked');

if (getPlaceChecked.next('label').text() === "") {
        previewPlace.innerHTML = 'No place chosen.'
    } else {
        previewPlace.innerHTML = getPlaceChecked.next('label').text();
    }
}
```

**HTML (actual form):**

```
<div class="custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-padding custom-control">
   <input class="custom-control-input" id="norway" name="placeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Norway">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="norway">Norway</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-padding custom-control">
   <input class="custom-control-input" id="sweden" name="placeCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Sweden">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="sweden">Sweden</label>
</div>
```

**HTML (preview):**

```
<p class="media-description" id="previewPlace"></p>
```

So far I've tried simply adding space like below. I've also tried appending, but it doesn't work the way I thought it would.

```
previewPlace.innerHTML = getPlaceChecked.next('label').text() + " | ";
```

Edit: typo in if-statement

Edit1: Made a quick fiddle to better demonstrate my problem  https://jsfiddle.net/d1nryuqg/

Edit2: Made changes in 'HTML (actual form)' to better fit the jsfiddle..

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed that and added a jsfiddle to better demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.text()` on a collection (of more than one element), it combines all of the values into a single string - there's no nice way to separate them.

Instead, you can use jquery `.map` to give you an array of strings for each label, then `.join` to separate them:

```
previewPlace.innerHTML = getPlaceChecked.next("label").map((i,e)=>e.innerText).toArray().join(", ")
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6p1h853t/

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input, highly appreciated. I think I'll settle with that.